# Linear regression with dates on x axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

As in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/trend-line-with-pgfplots-and-dateplots/89432#89432), I need to add a linear regression line to a plot which has dates on the x axis, but I get following error: `! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '2017-01-01' as a floating point number, sorry.`

Unfortunately, the dates are not all consecutive as in the [linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/trend-line-with-pgfplots-and-dateplots/89432#89432), so I cannot use the proposed answer, that is using `x expr=\coordindex`.

How could I do?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testtable.csv}
date;value
2017-01-01;0
2017-01-02;1
2017-01-11;2
2017-01-12;3
2017-02-01;4
2017-02-02;5
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testtable.csv}\testtable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [date coordinates in=x]
\addplot+ [only marks] table {\testtable};
\addplot+ table [y={create col/linear regression={y=value}}] {\testtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \pgfcalendardatetojulian will convert the date into a number.  See page 906 of PGF manual.

Comment: Intrernally pgfplots uses `% #1 the date
% #2 the hours
% #3 the minutes
% #4 is either empty or is the seconds. 
% #5 a macro which will be filled with the date part.
% #6 the macro which will contain a number in the range [0,1]
% representing hours and minutes.
%
% If you don't have seconds, you have to provide the second ':' sign
% as dummy! In that case #4 will be empty.
\def\pgfplotslibdateplot@map@time#1 #2:#3:#4\dateto#5\timeto#6{%`

Comment: @JohnKormylo I know about `\pgfcalendardatetojulian`. The question is: how to use this macro inside the `\addplot` command? Could you set up an mwe, please?

Comment: You can use it to create a new column using pgfplotstable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As was already suggested by John Kormylo in the comments below the question, the key is to convert the dates to integers in a new column of the data table.

For more details, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots(Table) v1.14
% (borrowed code from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302298/95441>)
\begin{filecontents*}{testtable.csv}
date;value
2017-01-01;0
2017-01-02;1
2017-01-11;2
2017-01-12;3
2017-02-01;4
2017-02-02;5
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}    % <-- to convert the dates to Julian integers
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  % <-- to manipulate the data file/table
    \usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testtable.csv}\data
    % add new column with Julian integer numbers
        % therefore a counter is needed
        \newcount\julianday
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/assign/.code={
            % convert the number of the current row and save it to `\julianday'
            \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\thisrow{date}}{\julianday}
            % then give the entry of `\julianday' to `\entry' which is then
            % given to the current cell
            \edef\entry{\the\julianday}
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
        },
    ]{JulianDay}{\data}
    % because the `dateplot' library shifts automatically all dates to 0 using
    % the first found coordinate we can't use the created `JulianDay' data
    % directly for `linear regression', but have to do the same first with
    % the data
        % get the first coordinate of the column ...
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{JulianDay}\of{\data}
        % ... and store it in `\xmin'
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmin}{\pgfplotsretval}
    % now create another column with the shifted values
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        expr={\thisrow{JulianDay}-\xmin},
    ]{JulianDayMod}{\data}
\begin{document}
% --------------------------------------------------------
%% for debugging purposes only
%% show resulting numbers, if you want
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[
%    column type=l,
%    columns={date,JulianDay,JulianDayMod,value},
%    columns/date/.style={string type},
%    columns/JulianDay/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
%]\data
% --------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[date coordinates in=x]
        \addplot+ [only marks] table [x=date,y=value] {\data};
        \addplot+ [mark=none]  table [
            x=date,
            % now we can use the newly created column to do the linear regression
            y={create col/linear regression={
                x=JulianDayMod,
                y=value,
            }}
        ] {\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]