# How to specify xtick={<>} when using x-coordinate in DATE-format and not using [date coordinates in = x]?

Tags: pgfplots, errors, pgfplotstable, calendar, dateplot

Depending on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/trend-line-with-pgfplots-and-dateplots/89432#89432) how to plot regression on DATE x-axes I post the MWE from Christian Feuersänger:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
date            value1
2010-01-01      2
2010-01-02      10
2010-01-03      8
2010-01-04      15
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% formats row \ticknum of the input table using '#3'
% #1: table name
% #2: column name
% #3: formatting instruction like \day.\month.\year
    \newcommand\datelabelsfromtable[3]{%
    \begingroup
    \countdef\result=\count200 %
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\ticknum}{#2}\of{#1}%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\pgfplotsretval}{\result}%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\result}\year\month\day
    %
    #3%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={yshift=-3pt,xshift=-4pt,rotate=-30,anchor=west},
xticklabel={\datelabelsfromtable{data.dat}{date}{\day.\month.\year}},
xtick=data,
]
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y=value1] {data.dat};
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y={create col/linear regression={y=value1}}] {data.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The regression-line on this works and I hope I understood his command. Using my data I want that PGF uses all of my specified data-points inside the .dat file. However, I don't want to use

```
xtick=data,
```

But I would like to specify for which data points the labels are written as the first half of my graph is not so important but at the end i would like to have more ticks. Using the exmaple data from the MWE, I would think of something lise this , skipping 2010-01-02:

```
xtick={2010-01-01, 2010-01-03, 2010-01-04}
```

I tried different versions of this just like {2010} but always receive an error (maybe because  the x dates are not declared as DATE? Doing so also result an in error).

So to sum it up:

How can I use the approach from Feuersänger (or if someone has another idea for using Dates when doing regression) but can specify which ticks are printed and not just using xtick=data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372049/95441 (as suggested also in your [parallel question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447550/95441)) using `xtick` there works perfectly fine ...

```
% used PGFPlots(Table) v1.16
% (code from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372049/95441>)
\begin{filecontents*}{testtable.csv}
date;value
2017-01-01;0
2017-01-02;1
2017-01-11;2
2017-01-12;3
2017-02-01;4
2017-02-02;5
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}    % <-- to convert the dates to Julian integers
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  % <-- to manipulate the data file/table
    \usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testtable.csv}\data
    % add new column with Julian integer numbers
        % therefore a counter is needed
        \newcount\julianday
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/assign/.code={
            % convert the number of the current row and save it to `\julianday'
            \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\thisrow{date}}{\julianday}
            % then give the entry of `\julianday' to `\entry' which is then
            % given to the current cell
            \edef\entry{\the\julianday}
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
        },
    ]{JulianDay}{\data}
    % because the `dateplot' library shifts automatically all dates to 0 using
    % the first found coordinate we can't use the created `JulianDay' data
    % directly for `linear regression', but have to do the same first with
    % the data
        % get the first coordinate of the column ...
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{JulianDay}\of{\data}
        % ... and store it in `\xmin'
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmin}{\pgfplotsretval}
    % now create another column with the shifted values
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        expr={\thisrow{JulianDay}-\xmin},
    ]{JulianDayMod}{\data}
\begin{document}
% --------------------------------------------------------
%% for debugging purposes only
%% show resulting numbers, if you want
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[
%    column type=l,
%    columns={date,JulianDay,JulianDayMod,value},
%    columns/date/.style={string type},
%    columns/JulianDay/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
%]\data
% --------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        date coordinates in=x,
        % =====================================================================
        % providing `xtick's works perfectly fine
        xtick={2017-01-01,2017-01-31},
        % =====================================================================
    ]
        \addplot+ [only marks] table [x=date,y=value] {\data};
        \addplot+ [mark=none]  table [
            x=date,
            % now we can use the newly created column to do the linear regression
            y={create col/linear regression={
                x=JulianDayMod,
                y=value,
            }}
        ] {\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]